# How to differenciate between Windows, MacOS (Darwin) and Linux in an ACPI dsl/asl source file?

Tags: bios, uefi, acpi

I am trying to disable S0ix sleep on Windows (As there's no way to force Windows to use S3 sleep, after the "CsEnabled" registry no longer works) and allow S0ix on Linux (S3 Sleep seems to be not working on Chromium OS). But I couldn't find a reliable way to tell what OS I am running in ACPI and patch in OpenCore. Something like doing the reverse of the following piece of code for disabling S3...

```c-like
// AOAC
// Name (_S3, ......
// In config ACPI, _S3 to XS3
// Find:     5F53335F
// Replace:  5853335F
//
DefinitionBlock("", "SSDT", 2, "OCLT", "S3-Fix", 0)
{
    External (XS3, IntObj)
    
    If (_OSI ("Darwin"))
    {
        //
    }
    Else
    {
        Method (_S3, 0, NotSerialized)
        {
            Return(XS3)
        }
    }
}
//EOF
```

Of course there're _OS, _OSI and _REV methods in ACPI standard, [but according to Linux kernel documentation, the Linux kernel is mocking itself up as Windows/Darwin](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/firmware-guide/acpi/osi.html). Though currently I could tell I am loading a Linux kernel, as Linux would return TRUE when querying if _OSI is Darwin. But what if I install Hackintosh in the future?

Comment: Note: If anyone just wishes to disable S0ix, aka Modern Standby, for Windows, check https://github.com/ElectronicElephant/Modern-Standby-Byby. My reason for doing this is, there is no way to switch from S3 to S0ix [without reinstalling the system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby), after CsEnabled registry not working. And my laptop no longer correctly sleeps without disabling S0ix. You wouldn't want to waste time reconfiguring your environment, right?

Answer (score 0):

you might enter BIOS setup menu to take a look

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately Samsung doesn't offer such an opinion to switch between S0ix and S3 in BIOS setting like what Lenovo has.

Comment: Before ModS support configured from BIOS, and related configuration existing in DSDT of ACPI. I took a look in above link. If you can reach following item, then S3 could be back 
1. disable Mods related chipset configuration
2. patch DSDT related region to let S3 back.
** I am not sure DSDT patch feasible or not. at least I did it, but system crashed.

Comment: So that's why I don't wish to hassle with BIOS and try to patch from "software" level. https://github.com/ElectronicElephant/Modern-Standby-Byby already did it. (Credit goes to Jamesits for developing the original [s0ix enabler](https://github.com/Jamesits/S0ixEnabler) ) It works but doesn't patch according to what operating system you are going to load. That's why I am trying to use OpenCore. It is intended to be used for Hackintosh and only patches DSDT for Darwin. The same could be done for Linux as long as there is a way to tell.